# Finding empty files in Python

Tags: python, filesystems

What's the best way in Python to find all empty (zero byte) files, recursively, from a given directory?  I could use os.walk and stat each file, but that seems very inefficient.  Thanks.

Comment: How are you going to know if they're zero-byte unless you `stat` them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you'd get more efficient than `os.walk` and `stat` since that's fundamentally what you're doing.  You could use some external command/service through Python's `subprocess.Popen` but then that's hardly "in python".

Comment: After doing some testing with os.walk and stat, it doesn't seem to be much different than the OS command "find <dir> -empty".  Given my minimal expertise, I was thinking there may be a better way, but apparently not.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make it work, then figure out how to make it faster.  You shouldn't start with a feeling that the most obvious way "seems very inefficient" If you want efficient, you can try the native OS.

```
os.system("find . -empty")
```